# How to retrieve object from Go http.Request?

Tags: json, http, go, get, httprequest

I have a working app that recieves HTTP GET parameters. They've been Strings and ints until now and it has worked fine getting each field using

```
http.Request.FormValue("field")
```

But now I've added an array of simple objects in the parameters and I don't know how to transform it to a slice of Go structs.

The array in question is

```
mods:[{
    name : x,
    max : 1,
    min : 2
 },{
    name:y,...
 }]
```

So I'm not sure how to proceed to map it to a Go struct. Should I create the struct first and map the result of r.FormValue using JSON?

Comment: I suggest you to use JSON format (or maybe [human JSON](https://github.com/hjson/hjson-go)). However, the object notation in your question is not a valid JSON. If you can't change the format, you need to implement your own parser.

Comment: @putu Sorry for the lousy question, I didn't have a JSON string to copy-paste so I hastily typed it out. It should be valid JSON. So can I just do something like json.Unmarshall(response.FormValue("mods"))? I'll test it out.

Comment: Yes, test it out. If you face any problem, you can update the question, or post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to fetch a set of [github users](https://api.github.com/users?since=135) and want to print their nicknames (`Login` field in `api.github.com`).

Given a User array example:

```
[{
  "login": "simonjefford",
  "id": 136,
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/136?v=3",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/simonjefford",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/simonjefford/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false
}]
```

You need a proper struct to handle it:

```
type Users []struct {
  Login string `json:"login"`
  ID int `json:"id"`
  AvatarURL string `json:"avatar_url"`
  GravatarID string `json:"gravatar_id"`
  URL string `json:"url"`
  HTMLURL string `json:"html_url"`
  FollowersURL string `json:"followers_url"`
  FollowingURL string `json:"following_url"`
  GistsURL string `json:"gists_url"`
  StarredURL string `json:"starred_url"`
  SubscriptionsURL string `json:"subscriptions_url"`
  OrganizationsURL string `json:"organizations_url"`
  ReposURL string `json:"repos_url"`
  EventsURL string `json:"events_url"`
  ReceivedEventsURL string `json:"received_events_url"`
  Type string `json:"type"`
  SiteAdmin bool `json:"site_admin"`
}
```

I suggest you to use [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to have a nice a clean struct given a json.

Then you can do the following:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "encoding/json"
  "net/http"
  "log"
  "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

  response, err := http.Get("https://api.github.com/users?since=135")
  if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
  } else {

    defer response.Body.Close()
    users := UnmarshalUsers(response)
    for _, u := range users {
        //Print each user's Login nickname
        fmt.Println(u.Login)
    }

  }

}
```

Where `UnmarshalUsers` is

```
func UnmarshalUsers(r *http.Response) Users {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var users Users
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &users)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return users
}
```

Comment: JSON-to-Go... what I time saver this will be. Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [encoding/json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package. In Go, you have to marshal and unmarshal your Go structures into and out of their encoding. It isn't quick an easy, but it's an good modern solution for a strictly typed language like Go.

In your case, you'll want to create a struct that matches the structure of the json you are trying to extract, and then unmarshal the json into a variable of the struct type you created.